# Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)-Ubuntu 22.10 when running Windows 10

Tags: drivers, kernel, virtualbox

I'm running ubuntu 22.04.1 -I just installed VirtualBox and im getting this error when running a Windows 10 on it.

---

Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing

'**modprobe** vboxdrv'

as root.

If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

---

And Second:

---

The virtual machine 'Winda' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Error code:
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component:
MachineWrap
interface:
IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}

---

This error is a bit different from what I saw on the internet. Namely that "modprobe vboxdrv". I don't know what to do now. It's very important to me but it doesn't work. A lot of popular solutions don't work. Perhaps this is due to Ubuntu 22.10.